# Spring Cassandra Repository First3 return all

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

Method is returning all values by parameter, not limiting by amount of 3

```
public interface PersonalOfferRepository extends CassandraRepository<PersonalOffer> {

  @Query("SELECT * FROM personal_offers WHERE core_id = ?0")
  List<PersonalOffer> findFirst3ByCoreIdOrderByPriorityAsc(TypeCustomerCode typeCustomerCode);

}
```

UPD. Same bug is with CrudeRepository

Answer (score 1):

You should extends `CassandraRepository` with cassandra rather than `CrudRepository`

Comment: Changed to cassandra repository same result as with CrudeRepository

Answer (score 0):

There is currently [no support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/759ef416eddc81e612e1a6f7234997c2758df910/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/repository/query/CassandraQueryMethod.java#L87) for pagination/slicing in Spring Data Cassandra. There is [a ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-56) open at their issue tracker.

If it were supported, you also need to know that repository query keywords (like `First3`, `ByCoreId`, `OrderBy`, ...) only work when you're not using `@Query`. If you're using the `@Query` annotation you are overriding the method name query.

If you would fetch only 3 results and you're using a custom query, then you'll have to use the `Pageable` parameter like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM personal_offers WHERE core_id = ?0")
Page<PersonalOffer> findByCoreId(TypeCustomerCode typeCustomerCode, Pageable page);
```

After that you could call your method like:

```
repository.findByCoreId(..., new PageRequest(0, 3, Direction.ASC, "priority")).getContent();
```

But since it's not supported (yet), you'll have to manually retrieve the first three results.

Comment: tried to implement both solutions, but both returned 22 rows not 3

  List<PersonalOffer> findFirst3ByCoreIdOrderByPriorityAsc(TypeCustomerCode typeCustomerCode);

  @Query("SELECT * FROM personal_offers WHERE core_id = ?0")
  List<PersonalOffer> findByCoreId(TypeCustomerCode typeCustomerCode, Pageable page);

Comment: How do you call that method now?

Comment: personalOfferRepository.findByCoreId(coredId, new PageRequest(0, 3, Sort.Direction.ASC, "priority")).size();

personalOfferRepository.findFirst3ByCoreIdOrderByPriorityAsc(coredId).size();

Comment: Can you also change the return type of the method with `Pageable` to `Page<PersonalOffer>`?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Slice and Page queries are not supported
 at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryMethod.verify(CassandraQueryMethod.java:82)

Answer (score 0):

as of the current spring-data-cassandra 2.0.7.RELEASE, you can use "Slice" with `CassandraPageRequest.first(3)`
have a look here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pull/114